# Passing API Token in Javascript: How to Keep it Secure

Tags: javascript, php, rest, security

The following script queries information from an API and outputs it into the HTML, using simple AJAX and Javascript.

The TOKEN for the API is exposed in the Javascript. In my opinion this is not safe because anybody who can access the page can see the token. IF this method is not safe, is there some additional method to hide the token? Ideally I would like to use Javascript, HTML, and PHP if needed. The existing script is very simple and so I'm wondering if there is a relatively simple way to protect the token.. rather than having to add a lot of additional new code or methods.

```
<html>
<body>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
     "url": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/eventid/?
token=TOKEN",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {}
  }

  $.ajax(settings).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    var content = "<h2>" + data.name.text + "</h2>" + data.description.html + 
data.start.utc;
    $("#eventbrite").append(content);
  });
</script>

<div id="eventbrite"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: definitely its not secure to call a private api from your client, instead you should call `your server`, and your server can then call the `eventbrite` api..

Comment: create a php script on your site that handles the actual call to the remote site and use ajax to send the request to your local php script ( so it acts like a proxy more or less )

Comment: Not only your "secret" key can't be secret in the browser, but on top of that, you can't even make a cross-domain request. The only solution to your problem is to use the server, not the browser.

Comment: Does your API provider return JSON or XML ?

Comment: It returns JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a simple proxy script on your server using PHP!

Your JavaScript will then call this script, including the event ID and nothing else in the GET parameter, so calling your PHP Proxy would be something like `/proxy.php?eventid=123`

To further fancify this example you could utilize `$_SESSION` etc to make sure your user has visiter the page before visit and only allow 1 request per pageload or something similar.

I have prepared a sample, but you have to modify it to fit your needs!

```
<?php

//Get event ID you want to request:
$eventID = isset($_GET['eventid']) ? $_GET['eventid'] : FALSE;

//Exit if no ID provided:
if (!$eventID) {
    exit('No ID Provided.');
}

//Set your token:
$token = '<YOUR_TOKEN_HERE>';

//Set url, %s will be replaced later:
$url = 'https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/%s/?token=%s';

//Set url, pass in params:
$request_uri = sprintf($url, $eventID, $token);

//Try to fetch:
$response = file_get_contents($request_uri);

//Set content-type to application/json for the client to expect a JSON response:
header('Content-type: application/json');

//Output the response and kill the scipt:
exit($response);
```

Resources:
[What is a Proxy (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server)

**Update:**
JavaScript:

```
$.getJSON('/proxy.php', {eventid: '<id_here>'}, function(response){
    console.log(response);
    var content = "<h2>" + data.name.text + "</h2>" + data.description.html + 
    data.start.utc;
    $("#eventbrite").append(content);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful. For the existing var settings, I'm trying modify those parameters to connect to the PHP script instead of the external URL, like URL=proxy.php?eventid=123 .. but wondering if that script also has to be modified further to work with this new setup?

Comment: @DanielC i have updated my answer with sample code of some javascript :)

Comment: wow thank you! Is there any other javascript that I need? When I replace my script with yours, I get an error in the console that 'data is not defined'

Comment: update: got it - had to replace 'data' with 'response' in javascript above.

Comment: @DanielC That's right :) i left it in there intentionally!

Answer (score 0):

You probably should not store the API key client-side, why not store it in the PHP scripts that the JS calls to?

If you really insist on storing it client-side you'll definitely want to encrypt it but I wouldn't want to rely on that.

Comment: This just moves the problem to the server. Now, all an attacker has to do is hit the PHP script on the server, rather than the API with the token.

Comment: I think we have different takes on what OPs goal is.  I assume OP has a public-facing API that relies on calls to some other API, and he is currently storing that other APIs token client-side.  That's insecure.  If he moves it into his public-facing API script on the server, the other APIs token is now secure.  It seems you are understanding the situation to be that this API token is to provide the user access to the OPs server-side API, but if that is the case then there is nothing wrong with storing the key client-side unless it isn't unique per client (but then that is the problem.)

Answer (score -1):

Store your API key one the sever and make requests to it when you need it. To make it even more secure on your server side only return the API key if a token (which you've set) is passed and validated to prevent spoof AJAX requests.

For example:

**PHP**

```
/** Change $_POST respectively to what you need. **/
if (isset($_POST['request_api_key_token']) && $_POST['request_api_key_token'] == 'your_value') {
    /** Return your API key. **/
} else {
    exit(header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden'));
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time following this. If I store the API key on a server, in a PHP script, then I call a function to get the token to put in the Javascript code above, doesn't that still lead to the token being exposed when it's passed to the page? Do you have an example of how the sample code I provided would be modified to work with your proposed solution?

Comment: Please share more details. As this prints the API key in plain text, isn't it readable for anybody in the browser now? How is this more secure than adding it to the markup directly?

Comment: @NicoHaase isn't that how most token based authentication works? Take Laravel Sanctum, the token is sent in the header which is very easily accessible. Sure, an argument could be made that the above is rudementary but like most security, it should be acompanied with other things.

Comment: Yeah, but the main question is: how to keep it secure

Comment: @NicoHaase sure, but I was adressing your criticism as you commented on a post from 2017 - and possibly downvoted it too. So, I ask again, what's the issue with having the token public if you lock things down correctly?

Comment: If the OP asks to keep the token secret, how does your answer ensure that?

Comment: @NicoHaase ok, I see you’re refusing to engage with what I’m saying. I see no point continuing this conversation.